# Posting multiple photos on instagram using React Native (Linking)

Tags: react-native, expo, instagram, deep-linking

Is there any way to post (or to open post flow) *multiple* instagram photos in one post using React Native?

For single photo, I used Linking:

```
const fullURL = `instagram://library?AssetPath=${encodedURL}`;

Linking.openURL(fullURL).catch(() =>
  alert('You should install instagram app first.'),
);
```

***encodedUrl*** - url of image which is being posted

Same approach doesn't seem to work for posting multiple photos in one Instagram post, unfortunately.